# Violation of Primary Key using import export wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have got the below message while copying the table from one instance to other:

```
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_RGENRL'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RGENRL'.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard).
```

Is it a good practice to DROP OR disable the PK prior to Importing the large records and re enable it again? any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: It's certainly not good practice to drop it if it is enforcing data quality and your import file is violating that data quality (which it clearly is). If something throws an error the solution is not to remove the error checking, it is to solve the issue causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your tables. If no duplicated allowed, you will not be able to re-enable the primary key constraint on that table since the PK will contain duplicates

Comment: I have got 3 PRIMARY keys in by table and interestingly all of their values are dups, and now when i trying to copy that particular table from PROD to TEST, i get this message ....

Comment: can you script your table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RGENRL](
 [DELETE_CODE] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 [ID_NUMBER] [numeric](9, 0) NOT NULL,
 [CURRENT_SEMESTER] [numeric](6, 0) NOT NULL,
 [COURSE_NUMBER] [char](8) NOT NULL,
 [COURSE_SECTION] [char](2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RGENRL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ID_NUMBER] ASC,
 [CURRENT_SEMESTER] ASC,
 [COURSE_NUMBER] ASC,
 [COURSE_SECTION] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RGENRL] ADD  DEFAULT ('') FOR

Comment: I really do not see how it could contain duplicates. No record can have the same course number and section in the same semester

Comment: I know that is how its suppose to be but i do have 4 PK as ID_NUMBER which has same value (3044) repeated over 100 times, PK_2 has same issue lot of dups, PK_3 Course number has multiple dups as well and the Course Section as well ..and i was wondering how come its a PK

Comment: I think the reason for having those dups is that is any student wants to enroll in to a certain course section ( 1or 2) , with XYZ course number for that particular semester (2015)he or she can have the save ID_number generated multiple times...

Comment: I think it's important to note that you do not have 3 primary keys on your table. A table cannot have more than 1 primary key. You have 3 columns that together create a single composite primary key. Your key will only be violated if you have a duplicate combination of a given set of those 3 columns. Edit, actually looking more closely at your comment, it looks like there are 4 columns in the key.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a SQL statement to extract the data and joins in this SQL statement cause duplicates.